# Loop multiple variable to form one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

What would be the best method to loop multiple variables into one table? Each variable could have one or more data points. For example, I wish to create something like this:

[image]

The following code example is only placing each item in a row.

```
<table class="table">
<% (@variable1 + @variable2 + @variable3).each do |data, v2, v3| %>
<tr>
    <% if data.is_a?(Variable1) %>
    <td><%= data.date %></td>
    <td><%= data.name %></td>
    <% elsif data.is_a?(Variable2) %>
    <td><%= data.date %></td>
    <td><%= data.name %></td>
    <% elsif data.is_a?(Variable3) %>
    <td><%= data.date %></td>
    <td><%= data.name %></td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Let's say, `Variable2` data contains an multiple value. Then check `data.is_a?(Array)` if yes, then you have multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since you don't know how many records might be in each array, I would find out the greatest length of the arrays I have.

In your controller for this aciton could do something like:
`@max_length = [@variable_1, @variable_2, @variable_3].map(&:size).max`

*Note: this assumes those variables are always arrays, even if they only have a length of 1.

Then in your view file you could do this:

```
<table class="table">
<% @max_length.times do |n| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @variable_1[n].try(:date) %></td>
    <td><%= @variable_1[n].try(:name) %></td>
    <td><%= @variable_2[n].try(:date) %></td>
    <td><%= @variable_2[n].try(:name) %></td>
    <td><%= @variable_3[n].try(:date) %></td>
    <td><%= @variable_3[n].try(:name) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

This way, for the third row, for example, in columns 1 and 3 in your example there will be no values, but values for the second column, which has a third record, will appear.

Comment: What a great answer. Really elegant way of doing this. Much appreciated.